# How to prove the inequality $\frac{4^m}{4\sqrt{m}}\le\binom{2m}{m}$ using chebyshev inequality

Tags: inequality

What is a good approach to proving this inequality:

$$\dfrac{4^m}{4\sqrt{m}}\le\binom{2m}{m}$$

using the Chebyshev inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality

I thought about using a random variable which has a binomial distribution, but im not sure.

Thank you!

EDIT: It is important to solve it only using Chebychev inequality

Comment: thank you, but this answer is not using chebyshev...

Comment: It is, but there are different Chebyshev inequalities, e.g. [this one](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chebyshev-inequality/), or [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality). Which one do you mean?

Comment: the second. thanks!